# Increase battery life on XPS 13 9343

Tags: dell, xps

I'd like to increase the battery life on my XPS 13 running Ubuntu 14.04. Is this possible? It seems like running a native OS like Windows performs better and would like to maximize the efficiency of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called `laptop-mode-tools`, which allows extending the life of battery. Another one is `pm-powersave` from `pm-utils` package. You can get either with

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install pm-utils
```

`pm-powersave` is mostly command line, have to be enabled with `sudo pm-powersave true`. `laptop-mode-tools` has a graphical front-end to it, written in PyQT.

For more info on both , check out [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower) and [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/install-laptop-mode-tools-164-with.html).